# Facing Issue with @PathParam Annotation

Tags: spring

I am trying to pass some data through URL using GET but I am unable to retrieve that data.

URL: localhost:8080/refresh-stats/abc
when I am printing the value of type then I am getting Null instead of "abc".

Below is the method in which I have put @PathParam annotation.This is under a interface and I am implementing below method in some other class.

```
@GET
@Path("/refresh-stats/{tpye}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getRefreshStats(@PathParam("type") String type);
```

Comment: I think there's an error in n write {tpye} instead of {type}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a typo in your parameter name. correct this `@Path("/refresh-stats/{tpye}")` to `@Path("/refresh-stats/{type}")` and try again !!